# Thread with Sleep not working properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, http

I'm trying to implement a method, that sends HTTP requests to a server and get the response in each two seconds.I need to add a new line to a rich text box which shows response strings. I used "Thread.Sleep(2000)" Method to pause the while loop.

Here is my Code

```
private void buttonRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var response = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:8181/");
            var responseString = response;
            richTextResponse.Text += responseString + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

But this is not working properly. it pause it self at the beginning and suddenly print the same string more than 5 times. What is the wrong with this. I'm testing the application in localhost. so there is no any connection issue which makes the application slow.

Comment: Sleeping on UI thread is a bad idea

Comment: You should really use a timer here, when you sleep the UI thread all the UI updates will queue until the thread becomes available again (hence why you see 5 updates at once)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.. but why Sleeping UI thread is bad can you please explain it for me.

Comment: @Sandaru I just did...

Comment: @Sandaru is it Winforms application?

Comment: Because UI becomes unresponsive. One basically cannot use UI until your code exits the while loop, which will never do :)

Comment: thanks for the comments ill try it using a timer

Comment: @ Sergey Berezovskiy yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `Thread.Sleep(2000)` on UI (main) thread, then your application stops responding to any user actions - it just hangs for 2 seconds. That's a bad idea.

I suggest you to use [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) component for this task. Add timer to your form (you can find it in toolbox) and set its [`Interval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval.aspx) to 2000 milliseconds. Then subscribe to timer's [`Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) event and do HTTP requests in this event handler. I suggest to use async handler to avoid hanging while waiting for response:

```
private async void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8181/");
        var response = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
        richTextResponse.Text += response + Environment.NewLine;
    }            
}
```

And start timer when you click button:

```
private void buttonRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start();
}
```

---

Another option is making your method async and usage of [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of making thread sleep (but I would probably go with timer, which is easier to understand and control):

```
private async void buttonRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8181/");
            var response = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
            richTextResponse.Text += response + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```